# Update Windows shortcuts on demand

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, shortcuts

If I change a file's location, its shortcut path is not updated until I double click on the shortcut. I want it to be updated on demand for **bulk** files in a path (reason: I move the files and folders to another computer and then by double-clicking on the shortcuts, they cannot be updated, so they don't work).

I found that shortcut updating is done by distributed link tracking, but don't know how to fix it.

My OS: Windows 10

Comment: First you say  the shortucts update themselves when accessed, then you say they don't. Can you clarify? It's easy enough to modify shortcuts via scripting, but not without example paths for shortcuts & targets. Please edit your question to supply more detail.

Comment: @KeithMiller I want to update them in bulk.

Comment: I get that, but with what information??? How can we update the Target without knowing where the files have been moved to? Will it always be the same set of Shortcut/Target pairs?  Are all the shortcuts in the same folder?, etc.

Comment: @KeithMiller not all targets are the same, but Windows knows all the targets. When we double click each shortcut, the targets get fixed automatically by Windows, but we can't click on 100 shorctuts every week manually. 
They are in the same folder, but in various subfolders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that viewing the **Properties** of a shortcut & selecting `Open File Location` also updates the Target location. So, short of finding the right APIs & some serious programming, We're stuck with resorting to `SendKeys()`.
After the `SendKeys()` sequence, if the folder with the shortcut was open for viewing prior to execution, if you right-click the shortcut & view its **Properties**, the `Target` *appears* unchanged. But this seems to be cached data. If you open a "fresh copy" of the folder, the shortcut's `Target` is updated. Edit as necessary & save a .ps1 file:

```
$wshShell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell
$Shell    = New-Object -ComObject shell.application

$LnkLocationParent = 'c:\path\to\FolderWithLnkFiles\'

$Shortcuts = gci $LnkLocationParent *.lnk -Recurse

$Shortcuts | ForEach{
    $oFolder = $shell.Namespace($_.DirectoryName)
    $oItem = $oFolder.ParseName($_.Name)
    $oitem.Verbs() | ?{$_.Name -like "P&roperties"} | %{$_.DoIt()}
    Start-Sleep 1
    $wshShell.SendKeys("%F")
    Start-Sleep 1
    $wshShell.SendKeys("%{F4}")
    Start-Sleep 1
    $wshShell.SendKeys("{Enter}")
    Start-Sleep 1
}
```